# Adding text with default font is outline without face

Tags: text-object

In all the tutorials I've seen when adding text the default text has a shaded/solid face. My default is just an outline/'faceless'.
I'm using 2.80 beta
Thanks

Edit 1:
Right,the question is why. Thanks for the suggestion and feedback.

Edit 2:
Israel -The question is why. I haven't changed any defaults. If you can answer your second question; '../ turn it to solid face?' then that would be a helpful workaround.

Edit 3:
This can be closed.
I had this problem using Ubuntu (compiled from source)
When I installed and tried Blender in Windows it worked correctly.
I re-compiled (very easy just make update and make) and moved the userpref.blend. It works. I restored the userpref.blend and it still works. Thanks for the help

[image: screenshot]

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I guess the question is "why?" Maybe he should show a screenshot

Comment: Is it why? Or how you can turn it to solid face?

Comment: What display mode (Z) are you in?

Comment: I ask, as I am on ubuntu, build blender from source, and the result above looks same as i get for render view, no light in scene. (EEVEE)

Answer (score 1):

How to turn Text to solid Face

[image: Text property tab]

Look for the "Fill" option under the Text Property Tab. Check if it is set to "Both" or "none"

[image: blender 2.8 text property tab]

Comment: Bamidele Thanks for the answer, Fill mode must have been set to 'none'.